# Network egress in google cloud explain?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm using a computed engine to deploy my video courses project which has NodeJS server as backend API and **serve videos**, frontend is VueJS will call that API.

My computed engine is in asia-east1-b Taiwan, and most of my user is from Vietnam. I notice at the billing dashboard has a huge fee of 'Network Internet Egress from APAC to APAC'. What is this and what part in my project causes this fee? How to cut down this free and not affect the current server (which is used by 1000 users)?

Edit: my total build is about 150$ and in that 23$ for the computed engine, and the network fee is 127$ just for 20 days ( 940GB)

I serve my video from computed engine ssd disk came along when I create the instance.

This is my instance and total bill and network bill info:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgwYc.jpg

Comment: Edit your question with details. Include details on exactly what is billed. Are you serving videos from your VM instance or from Cloud Storage? Review the different methods of delivering data and their egress costs.

Comment: Could you provide some sort of an anonymized cost overview?

Comment: my total build is about 150$ and in that 23$ for the computed engine, and the network fee is 127$ just for 20 days ( 940GB)

I serve my video from computed engine ssd disk came along when I create the instance.

Comment: My nodejs server use fs to read the video and send it to client chunk by chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, network ingress is free and network egress is what you are billed for. For more information about GCP network pricing I recommend you read this [page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing). So the billing you are seeing is not uncommon. Below is the cost overview of GCP asia-east1, here you can see that 0.12$ per GB corresponds roughly with your 127/940 = 0.135$.

[image]

But there are some things to consider to optimise your costs. First, I would recommend you redirect users outside APAC to instances in a different region. This is called geographic routing, to make sure you are not billed for inter-region egress. Inter-region egress is much higher than within the same region. But since most of your users are from within APAC anyway, this will not help a lot. This will only reduce the egress costs to a minimum of 0.12$ per GB.

I think the best thing is to look how you can reduce the size of the data you are egressing with a video compression algorithm such as H.264 or HEVC. There is a nice [post](https://superuser.com/questions/785528/how-to-generate-an-mp4-with-h-265-codec-using-ffmpeg) about how to compress video in such formats. You can also use caching methods so that data is not loaded twice to the same user within a certain timeframe.

I hope this helps you any further.

Comment: My instance zone is Taiwan asia-east-1b so if I block APAC traffic my user from Vietnam can still access my website?

Comment: No, only redirect users outside APAC to a corresponding region. But this does not solve your problem, since your user base is already in APAC. I think the only thing you can do is optimizing your streaming by minimizing the amount of GB that is streamed, without affecting user experience. Things that come to mind are caching and compression. Probably their are some other things you can do to minimize the egress. I would suggest you run some tests with alternative streaming methods. APAC still is the more expensive region when it comes to cloud costs, probably due to a lack of infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks @neubulastic, I have one more question all of my video is mp4 extension, and I only know one tool is ffmpeg to use, what algorithm option I can choose and pros and cons of it. And can you recommend some tool too?

Comment: I think ffmpeg is the way to go, updated the post with a link to good stackoverflow post about this topic.